# Deleting collection view cell swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview, google-cloud-firestore

Thanks in advance.
I have this collection view that populates from Firebase Firestore.
I am trying to delete a specific collection view cell that. which will also delete the fireStore document.
here is the code I have been trying but it only deletes the last item populated regardless of what cell I tap on.

```
func DeleteCell(cell: CollectionViewCell) {

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("news").document(documentID).delete() { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error removing document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully removed!\(self.documentID)")
        }
    }
    if let indexPath = CVControllerViewController().collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell){

        CVControllerViewController().collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])

        }
        }
```

Comment: did you checked correct cell is passed when this deleteCell is called, Are you using a Button in cell to delete specific item ?\

Comment: If you are using storyboard `CVControllerViewController()` returns a new instance of the controller which is **not** the instance in the storyboard and without connected outlets. The second call `CVControllerViewController()` creates another **new** instance which is not the same as the first one.

Comment: @iOS Geek, Yes I’m using a button in cell. It returns the correct cell however I can’t get correct documentID from that cell to delete it from Firebase.

Comment: A simpler process would be to delete it from Firestore and when you are notified of success, remove it from your collection and reload the view. As it is, the passed in cell could contain invalid data, the documentID appears to be undefined and if you want to stick with your code, move the cell deleting code into your else statement so it completes *after* the cell is successfully removed from Firestore.